# ISA Web Farm and WCF service hosted in a Windows Service with basicHttpBinding

Tags: wcf, web-farm

I have created a WCF service that needs to be hosted in a Window Service because it is participating in a P2P mesh (NetPeerTcpBinding). When I tried to host the WCF Service with NetPeerTcpBinding endpoints in the IIS Service container the service wouldn't run because it turns out that the P2P binding doesn't work in IIS.

I have exposed a HTTP endpoint from the WCF service hosted in a Windows Service container and I want to know if there is a way to create an ISA Web Farm that will route traffic to http endpoints on two machines each running the same WCF service in a Windows Service container.

Comment: Why does the title of your question states `basicHttpBinding` while you say that you have a windows service exposing a `netPeerTcpBinding`?

Comment: The wcf service has both. It is participating in a mesh using one contract and exposing a basicHttpBinding endpoint using a different, much more limited contract.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out quit a wile ago, sorry it took so long to get the answer posted.

Create a separate service contract called IDefaultDocumentService with one method on it that is decorated with both OperationContract and WebGet.

```
<OperationContract(), WebGet()> 
Function GetDefaultDocument() As System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message
```

Now implement that contact in a very simple DefaultDocumentService class

```
Public Class DefaultDocumentService
    Implements IDefaultDocumentService

    Public Function GetDefaultDoc() As Message Implements IDefaultDocumentService.GetDefaultDocument
        Return Message.CreateMessage(MessageVersion.None, "", "Hello!")
    End Function
End Class
```

In the config file for you windows service hook up a separate service for the DefaultDocumentService and map it to the root directory of your other WCF service. When you are putting these services into a Web Farm on ISA it will hit your default document service and get a "Hello!" message which is enough for the ISA server to know that the service is alive.

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <services>
    <service name="YourMainService">
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:10000/YourMainService.svc"
                binding="wsHttpBinding"
                contract="IYourMainService" />
    </service>

    <service name="DefaultDocumentService">
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:10000/"
                binding="webHttpBinding"
                behaviorConfiguration="DefaultDocumentEndpointBehavior"
                contract="IDefaultDocumentService" />
    </service>
  </services>

  <behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="DefaultDocumentEndpointBehavior">
        <webHttp/>
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```